# Friction at high speeds

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, drag

I am reading a book which mentions that frictional force is not exactly proportional to the normal force at high speeds. Quoting:

> Once the bodies slip on each other frictional force is, $kN$. This is approximately true for relative speeds not too large (say for speeds <10 m/s).

$$k = Frictional constant$$ $$N = Normal force$$

If so is the case,then what is the general way to find out the frictional force?

Comment: The units of speed? m/s or km/hr ...

Comment: Related, though not an exact duplicate: [Is friction always constant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116239/).

Comment: @SolarMike m/s, sorry I missed that

Comment: @JohnRennie Although the answers in that question touch the topic, they don't clear it enough. BTW thanks for linking that question. some good stuff there.

Comment: @user8850564 yes, which is why I didn't flag it as a duplicate. I don't think there is a simple answer to your question as the interaction between the surfaces is a complicated one.